# User Defined Error for date

Tags: validation, date, progress-4gl

How to validate an error for wrong date .
I would to validate in leave trigger itself

I used the following code, but not working :(

can some one help .

Thanksin advance.

Regards,
Ravi.
dtJoin is a database field .

Following is the code i tried .

================================================

```
    DEFINE VARIABLE vDATE   AS DATE        NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE vToday  AS DATE        NO-UNDO.

    DEFINE VARIABLE leap    AS LOGICAL     NO-UNDO.

    ASSIGN
    vToday = DATE(DtJoin:SCREEN-VALUE) NO-ERROR.

    IF ((YEAR(vToday) MODULO 400 = 0)OR(year(vToday) MODULO 4 = 0)AND(year(vToday) MODULO 100 = 0) )
    THEN
        leap = TRUE.
    ELSE
        leap = FALSE.

        MESSAGE MONTH(vToday)
            VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
        /* IF MONTH(vToday) = 1 /* OR MONTH(vToday) = 3 OR MONTH(vToday) = 5 OR MONTH(vToday) = 7 OR MONTH(vToday) = 8 OR MONTH(vToday) = 10 OR MONTH(vToday) = 12 */ THEN
    IF DATE(vToday) > 31  THEN
       MESSAGE "Invalid Date"
           VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
    ELSE
      ASSIGN
      vdate = vToday.
   */
   /*
    ELSE IF MONTH(vToday) = 4 OR MONTH(vToday) = 6 OR MONTH(vToday) = 9 OR MONTH(vToday) = 11 THEN
    IF DATE(vToday) > 30 THEN
       MESSAGE
       VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
    ELSE
      ASSIGN
      vdate = vToday.

    ELSE IF MONTH(vToday) = 2 AND leap THEN
        IF DATE(vToday) > 29 THEN
           MESSAGE 
               VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
        ELSE
         ASSIGN
             vdate = vToday.
    ELSE 
        IF DATE(vToday) > 28 THEN
            MESSAGE 
                VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR BUTTONS OK.
        ELSE 
            ASSIGN
                vDate = vToday.
                */
    END.
```

Comment: Is this some form of SQL? Add a language tag.

Comment: @doctorlove - NO, it is from Progress 4GL.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it very hard for yourself!

This ought to do it:

```
ASSIGN
    vToday = DATE(DtJoin:SCREEN-VALUE) NO-ERROR.

IF vToday = ? THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Enter another date" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.
```

You could also set the input field as date type and that will basically take care of itself. If you don't want that you could insert something like this in the LEAVE trigger of the field:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE vToday AS DATE.

ASSIGN
    vToday = DATE(SELF:SCREEN-VALUE) NO-ERROR.

IF vToday = ? THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Enter another date" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
    RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.
```